# Drop nan rows unless string value in separate column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop rows containing `NaN` values except if a separate column contains a specific string. Using the `df` below, I want to drop rows if `NaN` in `Code2, Code3` unless the string A is in `Code1`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Code1' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C'],    
        'Code2' : ['B',np.nan,'A','B',np.nan,'B'],    
        'Code3' : ['C',np.nan,'C','C',np.nan,'A'],                                   
        })

def dropna(df, col):

    if col == np.nan:
        df = df.dropna()

    return df

df = dropna(df, df['Code2'])
```

Intended Output:

```
  Code1 Code2 Code3
0     A     B     C
1     A   NaN   NaN
2     B     A     C
3     B     B     C
4     C     B     A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) + [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
new_df=df[df.Code1.eq('A')|df.notna().all(axis=1)]
print(new_df)

  Code1 Code2 Code3
0     A     B     C
1     A   NaN   NaN
2     B     A     C
3     B     B     C
5     C     B     A
```